# asp.net : A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: asp.net, web-services, base64, image-upload

I create an asp.net 4.0 web application which has a web service for uploading images. I am uploading images by sending the image in form of Base64 string from my mobile app to the web service.

Following is my code:

```
public string Authenticate(string username, string password, string fileID, string imageData)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> responseDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        bool isAuthenticated = true; // Set this value based on the authentication logic

        try
        {
            if (isAuthenticated)
            {
                UploadImage(imageData);

                string result = "success";
                var message = "Login successful";

                responseDictionary["status"] = result;
                responseDictionary["message"] = message;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            responseDictionary["status"] = ex.Message;
            responseDictionary["message"] = ex.StackTrace;
        }

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(responseDictionary);
    }

    private void UploadImage(string uploadedImage)
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(uploadedImage);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);

        string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("..\\uploads\\") + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpeg";
        ms.Close();

        bitmap.Save(uploadPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
```

This code was working fine on my local ASP.NET development server and I was able to see the uploaded image in my "uploads" directory. However, after transferring the code to the FTP directory, I am now getting the following error:

`A generic error occurred in GDI+`

I have checked that the upload directory has proper permission by creating a dummy .aspx page and creating a text file on page_load, and it works fine.

Even after doing google search, I was not able to solve this problem. Can anybody help me fixing this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of writing directly to files, save your bitmap to a `MemoryStream` and then save the contents of the stream to disk. This is an old, known issue and, frankly, I don't remember all the details why this is so.

```
 MemoryStream mOutput = new MemoryStream();
 bmp.Save( mOutput, ImageFormat.Png );
 byte[] array = mOutput.ToArray();

 // do whatever you want with the byte[]
```

In your case it could be either

```
private void UploadImage(string uploadedImage)
{
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(uploadedImage);

    string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("..\\uploads\\") + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpeg";

    // store the byte[] directly, without converting to Bitmap first 
    using ( FileStream fs = File.Create( uploadPath ) )
    using ( BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter( fs ) )
       bw.Write( imageBytes );
}
```

or

```
private void UploadImage(string uploadedImage)
{
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(uploadedImage);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);

    string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("..\\uploads\\") + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpeg";
    ms.Close();

    // convert to image first and store it to disk
    using ( MemoryStream mOutput = new MemoryStream() )
    {  
        bitmap.Save( mOutput, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        using ( FileStream fs = File.Create( uploadPath ) )
        using ( BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter( fs ) )
            bw.Write( mOutput.ToArray() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your reply, I'm not able to modify my code to include your suggested correction. Can you please post the suggestion by modifying my code.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks man, the first option worked for me. You saved my day! Many man y thanks... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore I think it's worth pointing out that when MemoryStream is used, stream must always be closed and  **save** method **MUST** be called before the stream closure

```
 byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
 memoryStream.Position = 0;
 Bitmap bmpReturn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(memoryStream);
 bmpReturn.Save(PicPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 memoryStream.Close();
```

Comment: In your example you would neet to add a try/finally to make sure the stream is closed in case of an exception. Anyway, you should always use the using statement for you resources! They are made for this.