# GDI+ Error - loading image in Asp.net. Student

Tags: asp.net

I faced problem in image uploading - GDI+ error. While doing my final course project in ASP.net. Please see below my full code of image loading:

The problem line is: newimage.Save(path + "/" + newImageName + Path.GetExtension(File1));

Can you please help me to solve this problem? Please make your explanation clear for beginner programmer.

Thank you in advance.

The full code:

```
private void ResizeAndUpload(FileUpload fileUpload1, MainCategory add, string path)
        {
            path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Media";
            var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var random = new Random();
            var results = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars,8).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
            string File1 = FileUpload1.FileName;
            newImageName = results + "_Categories_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");

            Bitmap original = new Bitmap(fileUpload1.FileContent);

            decimal originWidth = original.Width;
            decimal originHeight = original.Height;
            decimal ratio = originHeight / originWidth;

            int newHeight = 300;
            decimal newWidth_temp = newHeight / ratio;

            int newWidth = Convert.ToInt16(newWidth_temp);

            Bitmap newimage = new Bitmap(original,newWidth,newHeight);
            Graphics ographics = Graphics.FromImage(newimage);
            ographics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            ographics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Default;
            ographics.DrawImage(original, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

            newimage.Save(path + "/" + newImageName + Path.GetExtension(File1));
            original.Dispose();
            newimage.Dispose();
            ographics.Dispose();

            add.MainCatIcon = newImageName + Path.GetExtension(File1)
```

;

Comment: please try to check with the below link as it would help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698737/asp-net-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works.  Hovewer there is another issue: It works when I open 1 web master forms page in the project. But when I open 2 different web masters forms pages in the same ASP.net project - the imahe upload doesn't work in both of them. Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue.  Thank you very much in advance.